# Is writing tests a mandatory part of continuous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

There has been a debate going on between me and my development team. According to my study and research, Main purpose of CI is to add error free code to repository as early as possible. Writing tests is an important part of CI. Without tests, it does not serve the purpose.

On the other hand, the developer in my team says that writing tests is not necessary for CI, it is an optional thing. You can do CI without writing tests.

I want to clear this concept. According to my knowledge, CI does not serve the actual purpose if you don't write tests.

Opinions from developer community are required.

Thanks.

Comment: According to [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html), `Continuous Integration assumes a high degree of tests which are automated into the software`.